# VirtualBox can not create new virtual machines!

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to make a new virtual machine but, VirtualBox has this error then closes:

```
Failed to create a new session.
Callee RC: 
NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED (0x80040154)
```

In the terminal this is shown to me:

```
$ virtualbox 
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (3.16.3-1-ARCH) or it failed to
         load. Please reinstall the kernel module virtualbox-host-modules or
         if you don't use our stock kernel compile the modules with

           sudo dkms autoinstall

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

Callee RC: 
NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED (0x80040154)
```

Comment: can you please read the output you just posted as it tells you what to do.

Comment: i compiled this on my own kernel and installed  yaourt  -S virtualbox-host-modules

Comment: but now have those two error :

Comment: "Qt WARNING: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile" AND "Failed to create a new session.
Callee RC: 
NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED (0x80040154)
"

Comment: If you want to chit-chat, use comments.  On second thought, don't do that.  But, if you want to clarify your question (by adding supplementary information, like things you tried and other error messages), ***[edit]*** your question; don't use comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you haven't loaded the kernel module "vboxdrv". Use 'modprobe' to load the module and then try.
In case if something goes wrong try installing again the required packages. There is a pretty good documentation on [arch linux.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox)